# Which preposition is correct if a pizza is full of grease: "It was dripping in grease" or "It was dripping with grease"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

This is from a TV show, where a famous chef audits restaurants upon their request, and try the menus, and advises them what is wrong with some meals [Restaurant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03nrv09T7bs) (see:18:00-18:03) So, he orders a pizza which was full of grease, tries it and he said to the cook:

**It was dripping in grease.**

**"to drip in"** drew my attention. I looked it up and Cambridge says **"to be dripping *with* something".** not **"...dripping *in* something."**

So, Should it not have been **"dripping *with* grease"**?

Comment: Either is possible but it depends slightly on the situation, and whether the grease is in the pizza and leaking out, or whether they've poured oil over the pizza.

Comment: Note that it's definitely **not** "gripping" which is what you had in a few spots in the question (pay attention to the first letter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ngram viewer [suggests that](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dripping+in+grease%2Cdripping+with+grease&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) "dripping with grease" is about 5x more common than "dripping in grease", but it seems like both get used.

I would personally always use "dripping with", and "dripping in" sounds strange to me.

Comment: It's best to include an image of the ngram. If the link ever breaks (for example, if Google changes its URLs), then no one will be able to access it so your answer won't have any evidence.

Comment: I generally agree with this answer. I'll just add that "in" would be the most commmon preposition for some other participles, such as "smothered". And then there are participles such as "covered", which could easily work with either preposition. Participle/preposition combinations occur in a wide variety.